# how to input data for shapiro wilk test using python scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, data-science, data-analysis, normal-distribution

I am trying to do Normality test with my data.

```
# Method 1
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import shapiro

data = [1874181.6503, 2428393.05517, 2486600.8183,...] # there are 146 data points
data = np.array(data)
stat, p = shapiro(data)
print('statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print('its Gaussian ')
else:
    print('not Gaussian')
```

----Output----

```
statistics=0.582, p=0.000 
not Gaussian
```

---

When i run it i am getting its not gaussian, and when i calculate mean and standard deviation and generate sample using  np.random.normal(mu,sigma, 149) (sample shown below )then its showing as Gaussian

```
# Method 2 
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import shapiro

data = [1874181.6503, 2428393.05517, 2486600.8183,...] # there are 146 data points

data = np.array(data)
d_mu = np.mean(data)
d_sig = np.std(data)
data = np.random.normal(d_mu,d_sig, 146)
stat, p = shapiro(data)
print('statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))

alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print('its Gaussian ')
else:
    print('not Gaussian')
```

------ Output ----

```
statistics=0.987, p=0.212
its Gaussian
```

---

I am very new to Data analytics, It will be helpful if someone can help me on the below doubts

1. Which is the right method to do shapiro test ..? Method 1 or Method 2..?
2. I have difficulty in understanding the np.random.normal(d_mu,d_sig, 146) function . The definition given in docs is "Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution." But what data sample its generating , we already have data(my input data) and we have calculated mean and standard deviation to plot the normal distribution and the function returns some other data sample and **my shapiro test works for that**   ( i know i am completely taking it wrongly,  but not able to decide which one is right )
3. I am trying to do normal distribution for timeseries data . Any docs helpful links any one can suggest ...? to do normality test and to normal distribution . Anything that guide me in the right direction

Comment: *Any* set that comes out of `np.random.normal(...)` should show up as gaussian because that's what "normal" means.  What you've done here is take a distribution with possibly an infinite number of [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), asked `scipy` if it only had two moments and it said no.  Then you cut off all but two moments and asked again, and of course `scipy` said yes.

Comment: This is probably more a question for [math.se] or [stats.se]

Comment: @DanielF the "moments" you explained above is data points ..? . i was just following the example given in https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-normality-tests-in-python/ for the  shapiro test.

Comment: No, moments are the ways to describe your distribution.  A normal/gaussian distribution has two moments: first-order (mean) and second order (standard deviation) but most distributions have more (skew, kutorsis, etc).  When you're testing for normality you're testing for the number and value of the apparent moments.  If there appears to be more than 2, or higher-order ones, your normality test fails.  Of course, if you take only the first two moments of your distribution, and plug it into a gaussian number generator, the test will pass.  But that's just becasue you've removed the other moments